# Ошибка: multiple definition of в QWidget

Tags: c++, qt, qtcreator

Есть *.h файл со следующим кодом:

```
#ifndef CORECOMMANDS_H
#define CORECOMMANDS_H
#pragma once
#include <QString>
#include <QStringList>

struct MassageDataIn{
    QString operationId;
    QStringList names;
    QStringList values;
};

//Запрос базовых параметров ядра
const MassageDataIn cmdSetupRequest(){
    MassageDataIn massageData;
    massageData.operationId = "12";
    return massageData;
}
//Запрос состояния ядра
const MassageDataIn cmdSync(){
    MassageDataIn massageData;
    massageData.operationId = "11";
    return massageData;
}
```

Данный файл писался в консольном приложении и работал без всяких ошибок. После создания консольного приложение возникла надобность использования его в уже в QWidget приложении. При попытке скомпилировать проект на начальной стадии (только создал стандартный проект QWidget и подключил этот и еще несколько файлов, предварительно скопировав его с консольного проекта) получаю ошибку:

> 14: ошибка: multiple definition of 'cmdSetupRequest()'
>   UI\corecommands.h:14: first defined here UI\debug\core.o:-1: In
>   function `Z7cmdSyncv':

На форуме вычитал, что добавление `inline` и `extern` решают данную проблему и это действительно так. НО! Почему в консольном приложении можно обойтись без них, а в `QWidget` нет? Если все таки можно исправить эти ошибки без добавления `inline` и `extern` то как это можно сделать.

p.s. `pragma once` стоит во всех *.h файлах

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Определение не `inline` функций должно быть в файле реализации, т.е. `*.cpp`. Когда заголовочный файл подключается к разным файлам реализации, получается, что разные модули имеют в своём составе одинаковые функции. Линкеру плохеет и он говорит ошибку типа этой:

> multiple definition of `cmdSetupRequest()'

Ну и не хватает `#endif` в Вашем файле. Да и одновременное использовать разные *include-guard* как-то через чур всё же.

Comment: #endif просто не скопировалось. А почему тогда в консольном приложении все работает нормально?

Comment: @Madisson видимо, потому что включается только в один модуль (потому что других нет, где соответствующий `#include` присутствует) и конфликтов не возникает.

Comment: Ясно, спасибо за помощь.

Comment: @Madisson пожалуйста.